# JQuery Datatables : Add Filter on Click

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm trying to add a filter on a datatable by clicking on badges, instead of writing the entire filter into the field

Here is the input field :

```
<input id="dtSearch" type="search" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="" aria-controls="dtProjects">
```

I created tags inside my datatable like this :

```
<span onclick="add_fields('My Tag')" class="badge badge-success">My Tag</span>
```

Where my add_fields function is :

```
function add_fields(text) {
    var search = document.getElementById('dtSearch')
    search.value = text
}
```

The tag go into the input field but there is no Filter.
The filter appears to only work when writing inside the input field, or if I focus the input field and press Enter.

Is there a way to handle this ?

Thanks !

Comment: Depending on what event activates the filter, you'll probably need to manually trigger it. Something like `search.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));`

Comment: Thank you ! It was `search.dispatchEvent(new Event('search'));`

Answer (score 0):

This should probably help.

https://codepen.io/carlos27/pen/PvrLdX

I believe that you are looking for the following line to trigger the datatable filter (search)

```
table.search(btnvalue).draw();
```